# Azure Devops yaml file. configure it to do different thing when different path updates

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline which gets triggered if there is change in a path (Path A). This will then go ahead and install a component in the file Path A and build but now I want to expand this. I want similar thing to happen if a change happens in a different path (Path B). But I don't want the component to be installed when no change have been made to Path A. Is there a way of achieving this?
So in the trigger I have

```
paths:
    include:
    - File/Test

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/File/Test/'
    command: 'install'
```

and now for path B I will expand this

```
 paths:
        include:
        - File/Test
        - File2/Test2


- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/File/Test/'
    command: 'install'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/File2/Test2/'
    command: 'install'
```

But this will install the npm in both those file path when I only need the npm installed in the file path that contains the change. How do i got about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the condition in second task so that second task only run if task first will succeed.

Use below condition in second task.

```
condition: succeeded()
```

after modification of pipe line will look like belows.

```
paths:
        include:
        - File/Test
        - File2/Test2


- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/File/Test/'
    command: 'install'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/File2/Test2/'
    command: 'install'
    condition: succeeded()
```

for more details this Microsoft docs

[Azure DevOps conditions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: I want the second task to run instead of the first task when build pipline is triggered due to change in folder in file path file2/Test2

Comment: Check below similar thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573026/add-condition-on-stage-to-check-the-changes-on-folder

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227343/triggering-azure-devops-builds-based-on-changes-to-sub-folders?rq=1